# Newbie Sys Admin: How do I change global users?

Tags: apache, security

New on the job, small place, and the security stuff just landed on my desk. I was hired to be a front-end developer. Happy to learn new things, but never had to do sysadmin stuff before.

I started digging and it appears that apache, the site, and everything is running on root. There ARE no other groups or users. ACK!

What steps to I take to change this? I know that this is a big NO no...

Bonus points if anyone can please point me to a good basic 101 tutorial on apache/php security.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add new users using this commands on shell

first command adds a new user and second command sets a password for that user

```
useradd username 
passwd username
```

You can check some topics about server security from these links:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/apache-hardening/

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm

Comment: Thanks so much. How do I make sure that those users have the right permissions. Is there a way to switch apache to run off those new users?

Comment: This might help you, with group settings and permissions 
http://news.softpedia.com/news/Managing-User-Accounts-on-Linux-36645.shtml